# Setting contentSize of UIScrollView that is a child view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, contentsize

I have a view hierarchy like this:

```
-First View Controller
  -View
    -ScrollView
      -TBD
    -ImageView
```

I am trying to use the following (from apple docs) to set the content size of the ScrollView:

```
UIScrollView *tempScrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view;
tempScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,1000);
```

but I get error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
```

How can I modify to correctly set contentSize for the scrollView?

Comment: UIScrollView *tempScrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view; this line looks to be wrong going by your hierarchy, where is the scrollview set up? Have you created IBoutlet for it or made it in code? Your currently getting the UIView of the viewcontroller, which contains the scollView as a subView.

Comment: @BooRanger my scrollview was created in the storyboard by dragging the Scroll View out of the object library and onto the view.

Comment: Ok so you'll need to set-up an IBoulet so you can access your scrollView. This video will hopefully give you an idea of what to do, sorry I'm not on my mac to grab a srceenshot. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xq-a7e_l_4I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is this

self.view gets your main UIView for the controller, your scrollView is subview of self.view and to access this you'll need an IBOutlet.

So first thing is to create the IBOutlet in your viewControllers **.h**

[image: Create an IBOutlet for UIScrollView]

Then in your storyboard hook your scrollView that's ypou put in your viewContoller to the IBoulet.
Click the scrollView -> One right Utilities tab -> slick the right most tab, it will have a arrow in a circle -> Then click the Referencing Outlet and drag it over to your view controller  -> it will give you an option to either select the scrollView or view.

[image: Hook the IBoulet up]

Select scrollView.

[image: Select ScrollView]

That's it, now where you have your code just change it to:

```
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Auto Layout, then instead of setting the `contentSize` of the `scrollView`, you need to set constraints so that all the subviews inside the `scrollView`. Then your `contentSize` will be determined automatically according to your constraints.

Read [this post](http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/ios-how-to-use-uiscrollview-with-autolayout-pure-autolayout-approach-multiple-smaller-views/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller's view is not a scroll view, so the exception occurs.
Possible remedies
1. Change custom class of your view controller's view's class to `UIScrollView` tnen do like you did
2.
Set your scrollview's tag to 1000 then do as follows

```
UIScrollView *tempScrollView=(UIScrollView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1000];
tempScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,1000);
```

1000 is not mandatory, tou can put any integer, but make your that no other views of it or siblings have that tag

Comment: Please add a comment also while downvoting. Otherwise how users can understand whats the wrong with it

Comment: Changing the view controller class to UIScrollView is not possible as UIScollView is not controller, you would now have a scrollview hooked up to a viewController in the storyboard, this would cause errors. Also if you just mean the view itself its recommend to always have a UIView at top of the hierarchy. Using a tag is not correct way to reference a view in a storyboard, now if you were to put a thousand views in the scrollView then that's a perfect time to use tags.

Comment: @BooRanger sorry it was controller's view's class